# Unable to connect to smtp server

Tags: emails

I'm having some problems with sending e-mails from my drupal site.
It was working just fine before.

Some information:

The site is using webforms so I checked the issues here: http://drupal.org/node/344668
None of them solved the problem.

The server recently upgraded to a new version of litespeed (maybe this is relevant?)

The site is also using the STMP Authentication module.
It's using the gmail smtp: smtp.gmail.com
Running on port 587 (so with TLS enabled)
Authentication is required and correctly filled in.

Both e-mail addresses are filled in (the default server e-mail address and the e-mail address used by SMTP auth.), both of them are correct addresses in the form of info@sitesdomain.com .

The recent logs show 3 messages:

- Sending mail to: my@emailaddress.com
- Error sending e-mail from site e-mail address : SMTP error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
- Error sending mail from site e-mail to my e-mail address.

The drupal version is 6.2, webforms version is 6.x-3.2 and stmp auth version is 6.x-1.0-beta5

I've checked the STMP Authentication Support issue queue but there are no relevant item there that can help me. And if there are, then there are no answers.

I don't know how to take a look in the stmp log. I wouldn't know where to find it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: It's unlikely you'll be able to solve your problem without looking in the server's logs. If you provide information about the system the server is running, people will probably tell you where to find the smtp log in your particular case. Besides, Core 6.2 is very old ; upgrading it may be worth a try.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know upgrading the server is probably a step forward but at this point I am not allowed to. I've requested the system logs and more information on the server itself. I'll post more information as soon as I have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I mailed my hosting provider for some addition information about the server, the logs and such. And it turns out that they did not allow any traffic on port 587 except for traffic going to the google ip addresses. However google has recently changed the addresses for their smtp servers and the hosting provider did not.

So if there is anyone with a similar problem, I suggest you contact your hosting provider to see if they allow traffic to the google ip's on port 857 and if those ip's are correct.